# C : trying to implement a simple checksum but failing when packet data length is even

Tags: c, server, tcp, udp, client

so I'm developing a client/server app with my colleagues for one of our university courses.
We've been requested to make UDP reliable using TCP.
We were trying to add a checksum to our TCP segment to check is any data was corrupted, and so we did bu the function fails to calculate it at receiver side when the segment length is even.

Here is the code:

```
// in this function we create our segment

int make_seg(tcp segment, char *send_segm) {

    int bytes_written = 0;
    
    // copy the sequence number
    unsigned int* send_segm_ptr = (unsigned int*) send_segm;
    *send_segm_ptr = htonl(segment.sequence_number);
    send_segm_ptr++;
    bytes_written += sizeof(unsigned int);

    // copy ack
    *send_segm_ptr = htonl(segment.ack_number);
    send_segm_ptr++;
    bytes_written += sizeof(unsigned int);


    // copy flags
    bool* send_segm_ptr_flag = (bool*) send_segm_ptr;
    *send_segm_ptr_flag = segment.ack;
    send_segm_ptr_flag++;
    bytes_written += sizeof(bool);

    *send_segm_ptr_flag = segment.syn;
    send_segm_ptr_flag++;
    bytes_written += sizeof(bool);

    *send_segm_ptr_flag = segment.fin;
    send_segm_ptr_flag++;
    bytes_written += sizeof(bool);

    
    // verify for the receiver window
    send_segm_ptr = (unsigned int*) send_segm_ptr_flag;
    *send_segm_ptr = htonl(segment.receiver_window);
    send_segm_ptr++;
    bytes_written += sizeof(unsigned int);

    // send data field length
    *send_segm_ptr = htonl(segment.data_length);
    send_segm_ptr++;
    bytes_written += sizeof(unsigned int);

    memcpy(send_segm_ptr, segment.data, segment.data_length);
    char *send_segm_char = (char *)send_segm_ptr;
    send_segm_char += segment.data_length;
    bytes_written += segment.data_length;

    unsigned short int *send_segm_short = (unsigned short int *)send_segm_char;
    
    unsigned short int send_chsum = calc_checksum((unsigned short int*)send_segm, bytes_written);
    *send_segm_short = htons(send_chsum);

    bytes_written += sizeof(unsigned short int);
    send_segm_short++;

    snprintf(msg, LOG_MSG_SIZE, "make_segment \nseq num: %d\nack num: %d\nASF: %d%d%d\nData length: %d\nbytes written on send_buf: %d\n", segment.sequence_number, segment.ack_number, segment.ack, segment.syn, segment.fin, segment.data_length, bytes_written);
    print_on_log(fd, msg);
    memset(msg, 0, LOG_MSG_SIZE);
    
    return bytes_written;
}

// here we extract the segment @ recv side
int extract_segment(tcp *segment, char *recv_segm) {

    int bytes_recv = 0; // usefull to calculate the chsum
    memset(segment, 0, sizeof(*segment));
    memset(&(segment->data), 0, MSS);

    //deserialize sequence number
    unsigned int* recv_buf_ptr = (unsigned int*) recv_segm;
    segment->sequence_number = ntohl(*recv_buf_ptr);
    recv_buf_ptr++;
    bytes_recv += sizeof(unsigned int);
    
    // deserialize ack number
    segment->ack_number = ntohl(*recv_buf_ptr);
    recv_buf_ptr++;
    bytes_recv += sizeof(unsigned int);

    // deserialize flags
    bool* recv_buf_ptr_flag = (bool*) recv_buf_ptr;

    segment->ack = *recv_buf_ptr_flag;
    recv_buf_ptr_flag++;
    bytes_recv += sizeof(bool);

    segment->syn = *recv_buf_ptr_flag;
    recv_buf_ptr_flag++;
    bytes_recv += sizeof(bool);

    segment->fin = *recv_buf_ptr_flag;
    recv_buf_ptr_flag++;
    bytes_recv += sizeof(bool);

    // deserialize rcvwnd
    recv_buf_ptr = (unsigned int*) recv_buf_ptr_flag;
    segment->receiver_window = ntohl(*recv_buf_ptr);
    recv_buf_ptr++;
    bytes_recv += sizeof(unsigned int);

    // deserialize data field length
    segment->data_length = ntohl(*recv_buf_ptr);
    recv_buf_ptr++;
    bytes_recv += sizeof(unsigned int);

    memcpy(segment->data, (char*)recv_buf_ptr, segment->data_length);
    bytes_recv += segment->data_length;

    char *recv_buf_char = (char *)recv_buf_ptr;
    recv_buf_char += segment->data_length;

    unsigned short int *recv_buf_short = (unsigned short int *)recv_buf_char;

    segment->checksum = ntohs(*recv_buf_short);
    recv_buf_short = &segment->checksum;
    bytes_recv += sizeof(unsigned short int);
    unsigned short int recv_chsum = calc_checksum((unsigned short int*)recv_segm, bytes_recv);
    if(recv_chsum != 0) {
        printf("The segment has an error\n");
        return -1;
    }
    recv_buf_short++;

    snprintf(msg, LOG_MSG_SIZE, "extract_segment \nseq num: %d\nack num: %d\nASF: %d%d%d\nData length: %d\n, checksum : %d\n", segment->sequence_number, segment->ack_number, segment->ack, segment->syn, segment->fin, segment->data_length, segment->checksum);
    print_on_log(fd, msg);
    memset(msg, 0, LOG_MSG_SIZE);

    return segment->data_length;
}

// function for checksum calcultation
unsigned short int calc_checksum(unsigned short int*segm, unsigned int count) {
    register long sum = 0;
    
    while(count > 1) {
        sum += *segm++;
        count -= sizeof(unsigned short);
    }
    
    // add left-over byte if any
    if (count > 0) {
        sum += *(unsigned char *)segm;
    }
    
    // fold 32-bit sum in 16-bit
    while (sum >> 16) {
        sum = (sum & 0xffff) + (sum >>16);
    }

    return (unsigned short)(~sum);
}
```

Comment: The confusion about TCP and UDP might not be related to your basic problem with the checksum. Please create a [mre]. For example you can add a `main` function that calculates and checks a checksum of a buffer with fixed data without actually sending the data. What exactly means "the function fails to calculate it at receiver side"? Do you get a different checksum on the receiver side?

Comment: So it would be better to count up instead of down.

Comment: [RFC 1071: Calculating the Internet Checksum](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1071)

Comment: Your code will do different things depending on the system's endianness. For example, what `sum += *segm++;` does depends on the system's endianness.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Ok, so we should use hton to respect endianess? The fact is that i neither work on the same machine : it should give 0 as a result for the receiver, but for an even value of count it doesn't

Comment: @pierciro_caliandro Personally, I wouldn't write the code like this at all. The casts scare me because it's not clear how you ensure that the addresses are aligned. And what happens on platforms where the size of an `unsigned int` isn't 4 bytes? I consider this kind of code fragile and hard to understand and debug. I'd treat the data as an array of bytes and not try to cast it to other types.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thanks for the advice, we'll fix it